# Where is the signing menu in Android Studio arctic fox 2020.3.1 patch 3?

Tags: java, android, upgrade, android-studio-arctic-fox

I just finished upgrading android studio arctic fox 2020.3.1 patch 3 and I'm looking for a signing menu. Is it not in the build menu? Where is it?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's in the build menu. Look at this image, there is `Generate Signed Bundle / APK...`

[image: screenshot]

Comment: in my android studio there is no such menu, the build menu only appears as in this picture.
https://imgur.com/yQ4eV40

Comment: @RolyAudi Flutter? Are you using Flutter plugin and dart plugin?

Comment: yes, i'am using Flutter Plugin in android studio

Comment: @RolyAudi  If so, you can disable or uninstall them.

Comment: my problem has been solved. It turns out that the source code error that I generated from visual studio code